# Как написать функцию на с++ и интегрировать ее в python

Tags: python, c++

Я начала изучать этот вопрос. Использую swig. После сборки интерфейсного файла я не знаю как на python воспользоваться написанной функцией. Если будет полный пример,буду благодарна

Comment: А рассматривается вариант сделать в C++ dll файл и подключить его в python через `ctypes`?

Comment: Да,это хороший вариант. Сможете объяснить как это делать ?

Comment: А вы с C++ знакомы?

Comment: Да,немного знакома

Answer (score 1):

На стороне `Python` это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
import ctypes

# Подключение системных файлов
syslib = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt  # msvcrt.dll
syslib.printf(b"system DLL!\n")

# Подключение своих файлов
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./NAME.dll")
lib.PrintData()

# Вариант 2
lib2 = ctypes.CDLL("./NAME.dll")
x = lib2.SumData(5)
print(x)
```

в `Dll` соответственно реализованы функции `PrintData` и `SumData`.

Comment: А на стороне с++?

Comment: А с плюсами сложнее либо беру готовые dll-ки либо пишу на другом языке, так что тут пусть дополнят знатоки C++.